# What does Spectrum BASIC have that ZX81 lacks?

Tags: basic, zx-spectrum, sinclair, zx81

The Sinclair ZX81 has 8K BASIC interpreter ROM; the Spectrum has 16K. What extra features does the Spectrum put in the extra 8K?

The most obvious thing is commands for color graphics, which are absent from the ZX81 partly to save space, and mostly for the excellent and sufficient reason that the machine has no color graphics. However, it seems unlikely that the entire extra 8K, fully half the Spectrum ROM, is dedicated entirely to color graphics.

There is a BEEP command, though this seems unlikely to take much space.

The Spectrum optimizes arithmetic when the numbers happen to be integers; according to [Is there any significant difference in Sinclair BASIC of ZX80, ZX81 and ZX Spectrum?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/24344/is-there-any-significant-difference-in-sinclair-basic-of-zx80-zx81-and-zx-spect) the ZX81 uses the floating-point code path in all cases. Presumably this spends some space in return for speed.

The Spectrum tape I/O is faster. Does this code take up more space?

The Spectrum has about 1K of unused ROM space, due to development schedule pressure.

What else does the Spectrum use the extra ROM for?

Comment: I'm sure there are annotated disassemblies of the Spectrum ROM, as there are such for the ZX81. What did your research and investigation reveal?

Comment: You wrote *"it seems unlikely that the entire extra 8K, fully half the Spectrum ROM, is dedicated entirely to color graphics"* then state that you know 1 KB of it's unused. So there's only 7 KB. Meanwhile, have you compared the list of Spectrum keywords to the ZX81's list?

Comment: There used to be an annotated disassembly published as a book, if I remember correctly from Melbourne House? The book exists, I used to own it :)

Comment: You say *the ZX81 uses the floating-point code path in all cases*, but from [Reusing code, reverse engineering and collaboration](https://andrewowen.net/blog/reusing-code-reverse-engineering-and-collaboration/), it states that, building on the ZX80 BASIC, the ZX81 introduced `For the floating point routines, Vickers used a format almost identical to the 40-bit version of MBF. But he added the ability to store integer numbers in the range -65535 to 65535. The user doesn’t have to specify variable types. And it’s faster than BASICs that only store numbers as floating-point, such as Commodore’s.`

Comment: @ABMK - ***The Complete Spectrum ROM Disassembly***, by Logan, Ian; O'Hara, Frank. Published by Melbourne House, 1983. ISBN 10: 0861611160 / ISBN 13: 9780861611164

Comment: @Greenonline So it does! That is interesting, directly contradicting what was said in the other question I linked.

Comment: Yes, see also page ii (in the introduction), section titled "The arithmetic routines" in [The Complete Spectrum ROM Disassembly](https://ia800604.us.archive.org/view_archive.php?archive=/1/items/World_of_Spectrum_June_2017_Mirror/World%20of%20Spectrum%20June%202017%20Mirror.zip&file=World%20of%20Spectrum%20June%202017%20Mirror/sinclair/books/c/CompleteSpectrumROMDisassemblyThe.pdf). The two (integer/float) methods are explained in a little more detail  (but not much more). I've quoted that section in my answer, as it seems relevant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hopefully, this is a *pretty* comprehensive list of the differences between the ZX81 and Spectrum (and, to a lesser extent, the ZX80) BASICs:

- String handling
- No `FAST` and `SLOW`
- `UNPLOT`/`PLOT OVER`
- Additional (faster) method for storing integers
- Maths
- Multi-statement lines
- Scrolling
- ASCII
- Text display: `INVERSE`, `BRIGHT`, `FLASH`, `OVER`, `SCREEN$`
- String input: `LINE`
- Pixel graphics: `LINE`, `CIRCLE`, `DRAW`, `POINT`. Also `PLOT`
- Colour: `BORDER`, `PAPER`, `INK`, `ATTR`
- Sound: `BEEP`
- Typographical
- Files and channels
- Fixed video RAM
- Input/Output: `IN`, `OUT`
- Binary: `BIN`
- Tape files: `VERIFY` and `MERGE`. Also modifiers: `LINE`, `DATA()`, `DATA$()`, `CODE` and `SCREEN$`
- Faster, better tape loading and saving
- String evaluation: `VAL$`
- Microdrives: `MOVE`, `ERASE`, `CAT`, `FORMAT`
- Functions: `DEF FN` and `FN`
- Data: `READ`, `RESTORE`, `DATA`
- User defined characters
- Key repeat

This list (mostly) omits the enhancements when plugging in *Interface 1*.

Nevertheless, such a substantial list of changes looks like it could fill 7 kB of additional ROM space.

---

Looking at each in a little more detail...

##### String handling

ZX80 offered no string manipulation, whereas the ZX81 introduced `n TO m` - to simplify (and reduce memory). The Spectrum continued the use of `TO`, *possibly* with no further enhancements to the ZX81 functionality (I can't remember).

##### No `FAST` and `SLOW`

The ZX81 had `FAST` and `SLOW` keywords, for the two modes of operation. The Spectrum did away with these modes, and hence the keywords.

##### `UNPLOT`/`PLOT OVER`

The ZX81 has a third command the Spectrum doesn't have: `UNPLOT`. On the Spectrum, the same effect can be achieved by using `PLOT OVER` with the same x- and y-coordinates.

##### Additional (faster) method for storing integers

The ZX80 handled all numbers as integers. The ZX81 added floating point support but also added an "integer only" storage method, for numbers between -65535 to 65535, that was *faster* than the floating point storage. From [Reusing code, reverse engineering and collaboration](https://andrewowen.net/blog/reusing-code-reverse-engineering-and-collaboration/):

> For the floating point routines, Vickers used a format almost identical to the 40-bit version of MBF. But he added the ability to store integer numbers in the range -65535 to 65535. The user doesn’t have to specify variable types. And it’s faster than BASICs that only store numbers as floating-point, such as Commodore’s.

The Spectrum *also* had this faster integer storage method. From [The Complete Spectrum ROM Disassembly, by Logan, Ian; O'Hara, Frank](https://ia800604.us.archive.org/view_archive.php?archive=/1/items/World_of_Spectrum_June_2017_Mirror/World%20of%20Spectrum%20June%202017%20Mirror.zip&file=World%20of%20Spectrum%20June%202017%20Mirror/sinclair/books/c/CompleteSpectrumROMDisassemblyThe.pdf), on page ii (in the Introduction):

> **The arithmetic routines**
>
> The Spectrum has two forms for numbers. Integer values in the range
> -65535 to +65535 are in an 'integral' or 'short' form whilst all other numbers are in a five byte floating point form.
>
> The present version of the monitor is unfortunately marred by two
> mistakes in this part.
>
> i. There is a mistake in 'division' whereby the 34th bit of a division is lost.
> ii. The value of -65536 is sometimes put in 'short' form
> and at other times in 'floating-point' and this leads to troubles.

##### Maths

> Vickers further improved the math pacakge

... for the Spectrum, over the ZX81. How is was improved is unclear.

##### Multi-statement lines

The ZX81 only allowed one statement per line number. The Spectrum allowed multi-statement lines.

##### Scrolling

The ZX81 doesn't scroll the screen automatically like the Spectrum does, you have to use a specific command, `SCROLL`.

See also the scrolling issues hinted at in the section **Fixed video RAM**, below.

##### ASCII

The ZX81 only has a limited character set with only upper case using non-ASCII values, whereas the Spectrum supports ASCII and lower case characters.

As a result, the inverse characters and half-tone "checkerboard" characters was lost on the Spectrum. However, the **User defined characters**, see section below, introduced with the Spectrum, and the `INVERSE` text modifier, could be used to work around these "lost" characters.

##### Text display: `INVERSE`, `BRIGHT`, `FLASH`, `OVER`, `SCREEN$`

The Spectrum allowed effects to be added to text characters, using the `INVERSE`, `BRIGHT`, `FLASH`, `OVER` commands. The ZX80/ZX81 did not.

The Spectrum added a way to read a character on the display, using `SCREEN$`:

> The character that appears, either normally or inverted, on the television at line x, column y. Gives the empty string, if the character is not recognised. Error B unless 0<=x<=23 and 0<=y<=31.

##### String input: `LINE`

The Spectrum offered an string input that suppressed the double quotes being printed:

```
10 INPUT LINE A$
```

IIRC, *Interface 1* also made use of this command by repurposing it, depending upon context.

##### Pixel graphics: `LINE`, `CIRCLE`, `DRAW`, `POINT`. Also `PLOT`

The Spectrum gains all the pixel-manipulation commands: `LINE`, `CIRCLE` and `DRAW`.

`PLOT` now means a single pixel, whereas, IIRC, on the ZX81 a "pixel" was in fact a 4x4 pixel block .

> `POINT` returns 1 if the pixel at (x,y) is ink colour. 0 if it is paper colour. Error B unless 0<=x<=255 and 0<=y<= 175.

##### Colour: `BORDER`, `PAPER`, `INK`, `ATTR`

For colour manipulation the Spectrum gains the `INK` and `PAPER` commands, and `BORDER`. `ATTR` would give the display attributes of a character location on screen,

##### Sound: `BEEP`

The ZX80 and ZX81 had no sound capability (unless some funky screen blanking code was used to create a buzz in order to approximate a noise but this was a side-effect, not a *feature*).

The command `BEEP` provided sound on the Spectrum (plus `PLAY` on the 128k).

##### Typographical

There are minor typographical changes (ZX81 -> Spectrum):

- `GOTO` -> `GO TO`
- `GOSUB` -> `GO SUB`
- `RAND` -> `RANDOMIZE` ([the ZX80 used `RANDOMISE`](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/26117/202))
- `CONT` -> `CONTINUE`
- etc.

##### Files and channels

- The Spectrum offers more with files, and introduces streams: `MERGE`, `VERIFY`, `SCREEN$`, and `OPEN`/`CLOSE` `#`.

Additionally, for the Spectrum:

> because the hardware design was incomplete, [Vickers] created a hardware abstraction layer of channels and streams.

This functionality was later "fleshed out" with the use of *Interface 1* (not covered here).

##### Fixed video RAM

The unexpanded base model of the ZX81 used an "elastic" (and rather annoying) memory map, with the video starting at `D_FILE`, that expanded (and contracted?) as the screen was filled (or emptied) (IIRC, this was due to ZX81 having to accommodate for the very limited 1 kB RAM available). It also moved around as the BASIC program residing beneath it grew or shrank.

[image: Partial ZX81 memory map, showing the display map]

However, if a 16 kB RAM pack was used and detected, then the video memory automatically maxed out its size.

It is better explained on page 74, chapter 27 of the ZX81 BASIC manual - the ***emphasis*** is mine:

> The display file is the memory copy of the television picture. It begins with a NEWLINE character, & then has the twenty four lines of text, each finishing with a NEWLINE. The system is so designed that a line of text does not need space a full thirty two characters: final spaces can be omitted. ***This is used to save space when the memory is small***.
>
> When the total amount of memory (according to the system variable `RAMTOP`) is less than 3 1/4 K, then a clear screen - as set up at the start or by `CLS` - consists of just twenty five NEWLINEs. When the memory is bigger than a clear screen is padded out with 24*32 spaces & on the whole it stays at its full size; `SCROLL`, however, & certain conditions where the lower part of the screen expands to more than two lines, can upset this by introducing short lines at the bottom.

The Spectrum was, IMHO, much easier to use as it had a fixed memory map for the RAM, with the map for the video being split into two sections:

> - 6144 bytes worth of bitmap data, starting at memory address &4000
> - 768 byte colour attribute data, immediately after the bitmap data at address &5800

##### Input/Output: `IN`, `OUT`

The Spectrum added the ability to access the I/O space of the Z80 from within BASIC. To access the I/O space on the ZX81 you had to resort to using machine code.

According to [Appendix C of the Spectrum manual](https://worldofspectrum.org/ZXBasicManual/zxmanappc.html):

> `IN` - The result of inputting at processor level from port x (0<=x<=FFFFh) (loads the bc register pair with x and does the assembly language instruction in a(c))

IIRC, these two commands were later re-purposed and used by *Interface 1*, depending on context.

##### Binary: `BIN`

> An alternative notation for numbers: `BIN` followed by a sequence of 0s and 1s is the number with such a representation in binary

##### Tape files: `VERIFY` and `MERGE`.  Also modifiers: `LINE`, `DATA()`, `DATA$()`, `CODE` and `SCREEN$`

`VERIFY` and `MERGE` was introduced with the Spectrum, for enhanced tape based file storage, allowing you to verify a saved file, and to merge a saved file.

Several modifiers, used in conjunction with the `LOAD` and `SAVE` commands, were introduced with the Spectrum:

- Saving a program using `LINE` allowed a loaded program to auto-run.
- `SCREEN$` was used to save and load a bitmap of the screen.
- `CODE` was used to save and load a code block.
- `DATA()` was used to save and load a numeric array.
- `DATA$()` was used to save and load a character array.

##### Faster, better tape loading and saving

The Spectrum improved the routines used for loading and saving for faster performance, over those used for the ZX81.

From [The Complete Spectrum ROM Disassembly, by Logan, Ian; O'Hara, Frank](https://ia800604.us.archive.org/view_archive.php?archive=/1/items/World_of_Spectrum_June_2017_Mirror/World%20of%20Spectrum%20June%202017%20Mirror.zip&file=World%20of%20Spectrum%20June%202017%20Mirror/sinclair/books/c/CompleteSpectrumROMDisassemblyThe.pdf), on page i (in the Introduction), - the ***emphasis*** is mine:

> **The cassette handling routines.**
>
> It was a very unfortunate feature of the ZX 81 that so little of the
> monitor program for that machine was devoted to the cassette handling.
>
> However in the Spectrum there is an ***extensive block of code*** and now
> the high standard of cassette handling is one of the most successful
> features of the machine.
>
> BASIC programs or blocks of data are both dealt with in the same
> manner of having a 'header' block (seventeen bytes) that is SAVEd
> first. This 'header' describes the 'data block' that is SAVEd after
> it.
>
> One disadvantage of this system is that it is not possible to produce
> programs with any 'security' whatsoever.

##### String evaluation: `VAL$`

The ZX81 has `VAL`

> Evaluates x (without its bounding quotes) as a numerical expression.
> Error C if x contains a syntax error, or gives a string value. Other errors possible, depending on the expression

However, the Spectrum added `VAL$`.

> Evaluates x (without its bounding quotes) as a string expression.
> Error C if x contains a syntax error or gives a numeric value. Other errors possible, as for VAL

##### Microdrives: `MOVE`, `ERASE`, `CAT`, `FORMAT`

These commands required *Interface 1* to be attached, I don't think that they did anything useful without it.

##### Functions: `DEF FN` and `FN`

The Spectrum added the ability to define functions.

##### Data: `READ`, `RESTORE`, `DATA`

The Spectrum added the ability to store data in the program.

##### User defined characters

The Spectrum introduced 21 user defined characters, mapped to the letters keys A-U.

##### Key repeat

The Spectrum also had **key-repeat**, upon an extended key press. Which I don't think that the ZX81 had.

---

##### References

- [zx spectrum and zx81 BASIC differences?](https://www.reddit.com/r/zxspectrum/comments/o2poeo/zx_spectrum_and_zx81_basic_differences/)
- [Reusing code, reverse engineering and collaboration](https://andrewowen.net/blog/reusing-code-reverse-engineering-and-collaboration/)
- [Screen Memory Layout](http://www.breakintoprogram.co.uk/hardware/computers/zx-spectrum/screen-memory-layout)
- [Peeking into the ZX81s Screen Maze](https://www.zx81keyboardadventure.com/2017/03/peeking-into-zx81s-screen-maze.html)
- [Appendix C of the Spectrum manual](https://worldofspectrum.org/ZXBasicManual/zxmanappc.html)
- [The Complete Spectrum ROM Disassembly, by Logan, Ian; O'Hara, Frank](https://ia800604.us.archive.org/view_archive.php?archive=/1/items/World_of_Spectrum_June_2017_Mirror/World%20of%20Spectrum%20June%202017%20Mirror.zip&file=World%20of%20Spectrum%20June%202017%20Mirror/sinclair/books/c/CompleteSpectrumROMDisassemblyThe.pdf)

Answer (score 14):

From '[Reusing Code, Reverse Engineering And Collaboration](https://andrewowen.net/blog/reusing-code-reverse-engineering-and-collaboration/)':

> Grant and Vickers would’ve liked to start over, but there wasn’t time.
> So the ZX81 BASIC was used as the starting point, with the addition of
> color, graphics and sound commands. Vickers further improved the math package. And because the hardware design was incomplete, he
> created a hardware abstraction layer of channels and streams. But
> three months before launch, Vickers and Altwasser both resigned to
> form the Cantab company to produce the Jupiter ACE (essentially a ZX81
> with Forth in place of BASIC).
>
> The ZX Spectrum was launched in April 1982. But work on the RS232,
> networking and microcassette storage system was unfinished, and the
> BASIC was incomplete. Sinclair packaged this functionality in a
> hardware add-on called the Interface 1. It had its own firmware
> written by Ian Logan (who had taken Frank O’Hara’s disassembly of the
> ZX81 BASIC as a starting point and written a disassembly of the ZX
> Spectrum BASIC).

There are lots of other differences, e.g.the Spectrum has bitmapped screen, lower case, so the text routines and font tables need to be larger. You can read the whole ROM disassembly [here](http://www.primrosebank.net/computers/zxspectrum/docs/CompleteSpectrumROMDisassemblyThe.pdf).

Comment: This is very interesting but it doesn't answer the question. Are you saying that the entire extra 7K was taken up with graphics sound and the IO abstraction layer?

Comment: Also the 16kb isn’t entirely full; I think it’s mostly so, but 16kb is the next ROM size up from 8kb while keeping things cheap.

Comment: There are 1170 bytes unused: 386E - 3CFF These locations are 'spare'. They all hold +FF

Comment: Another half kilobyte is the difference in character ROM. ZX-81 has bitmaps for code points 00-3F (1E00-1FFF), Spectrum has 00-7F (3D00-3FFF).

Comment: @JeremyP The Spectrum's BASIC adds several other things that aren't mentioned in this answer. DEF FN, READ, DATA, RESTORE and VAL$ spring to mind.

Comment: I'm afraid this says a lot but I can't say it answers the actual question, so downvoting for that reason. I am a bit surprised @rwallace accepted this as the answer...it's quite vague and undetailed on that which the question asked about.

Comment: The Jupiter ACE is _not_ essentially a ZX81 with Forth, a ZX81 with a Forth ROM is. :-D Actually, the hardware is completely different. (Unless you count the same CPU and similar video output as being enough.)

Comment: @thebusybee, what hardware? Other than the obvious CPU and display, there is not much to either a ZX81 or a Jupiter Ace.

Comment: @OmarandLorraine Look at the schematics, and you will find ULA vs TTL logic, and RAM and ROM.

Comment: @OmarandLorraine And the video logic is totally different...

Comment: I *think* the ZX81 only supported integer maths, but the Spectrum had floating point maths and a fairly extensive set of maths functions to go with it.

Comment: @Stormcloud See the OP's question, the ZX81 uses float math.

Comment: You've edited this to put some of it in shouty bold, which I find makes it less readable, not more - be better with no shouty bold. But there's still no text explaining it in decent lengthy detail, no lists of the new commands, just 'go and read a whole disassembly'...still very sketchy, I'm afraid. I have read the whole Spectrum disassembly in great detail and it wouldn't help me answer the OP's question.

Comment: @TonyM indeed and a much better answer has now arrived.

Comment: That reads almost like a weight's been lifted :-) Either way, I really appreciate the decency in your honesty. Have removed bold, tidied links and removed my downvote. Have a great day.

Comment: @busybee, you are absolutely right - it was the ZX80 that only supported integer arithmetic. I've confused the two.